# How can I pass a smarty variable to a php function?

Tags: php, html, smarty

**PHP CODE:**

```
function show_playlist_form($array)
{
    global $cbvid;
    assign('params',$array);

    $playlists = $cbvid->action->get_channel_playlists($array);
    assign('playlists',$playlists);

    Template('blocks/playlist_form.html');
}
```

**HTML CODE (SMARTY INSIDE):**

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
{show_playlist_form}
</body>
</html>
```

This all can be found in clip-bucket video script. The html code calls the php function, where it shows **playlist_form.html**. However, I'm interested in adding an integer value in the smarty defined tag **show_playlist_form** so that it would pass it to the function in php **show_playlist_form($array)** and then the function would assign the integer into **$array**.

I tried, assuming I'm interested in passing the integer **1**:

```
{show_playlist_form(1)}
```

**Fatal error:** Smarty error: [in /home/george/public_html/styles/george/layout/view_channel.html line 4]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: show_playlist_form(1) (Template_Compiler.class.php, line 447) in **/home/george/public_html/includes/templatelib/Template.class.php** on line **1095**

```
{show_playlist_form array='1'}
```

The html code worked but it I got nothing (blank).

So, it didn't work, what can I do? I need to pass integer values to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for here is to implement a "custom template function" which receives parameters.

As shown in [the documentation on function plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl), the function you create will receive two parameters:

- an associative array of named parameters from the Smarty tag
- an object representing the current template (useful for e.g. assigning additional Smarty variables)

---

So for instance, if you define this:

```
function test_smarty_function($params, $smarty) {
      return $params['some_parameter'], ' and ', $params['another_parameter'];
}
```

And register it with Smarty under the name `test` like this:

```
$template->registerPlugin('function', 'test', 'test_smarty_function');
```

Then you could use it in your templates like this:

```
{test some_parameter=hello another_parameter=goodbye}
```

Which should output this:

```
hello and goodbye
```

---

In your case, you probably want something like this:

```
function show_playlist_form($params, $smarty) {
     $playlist_id = $params['id'];
     // do stuff...
}
```

and this:

```
{show_playlist_form id=42}
```

Comment: +10 if I could for the explanation! Very well answered.

Comment: I've got also this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923044/call-smarty-variable-from-html-instead-of-php).