# Call smarty variable from html instead of php

Tags: php, html, smarty

**HTML CODE:**

> ```
> <html><body>
> {section name=a loop=$items}
> {$items[a].title}
> {include file="/directory/showstuff.html" video=$items[a]}
> {/section}
> </body> </html>
> ```

**PHP CODE:**

> $pid = '12';
>
> $items = $cbvid->get_channel_items($pid);
>
> assign('items',$items);

This is perfectly working fine, with the integer **12** being my php code. However, I wanted to add the integer **12** and call it from the html code, but it didn't work.

I tried:

> ```
> <html><body>
> {section name=a loop=$cbvid->get_channel_items(12)}
> {$items[a].title}
> {include file="/directory/showstuff.html" video=$items[a]}
> {/section}
> </body> </html>
> ```

But it didn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't do it. That looks like if you would like to move business logic to representation layer - that is not what Smarty is used for. Prepare data beforehand, then give it to template.

But if you really want it to work, use `foreach`

```
<html><body>
{foreach  from=$cbvid->get_channel_items(12) item=video}
{$video.title}
{include file="/directory/showstuff.html" video=$video}
{/foreach}
</body> </html>
```

The reason why it did not work with sections, was because you have no `$items` variable defined, still, you are trying to get value of it. This is where you need to use `assign`.

```
<html><body>
{assign var="items" value=$cbvid->get_channel_items(12)}
{section name=a loop=$items}
{$items[a].title}
{include file="/directory/showstuff.html" video=$items[a]}
{/section}
</body> </html>
```

Still, I prefer `foreach`.

Comment: Very much appreciated. :)